# Battery charge drops very quickly while internet connection is on

Tags: battery, battery-life, 7.0-nougat

*There are many questions like this, but mine is slightly different from those.*

I am facing these weird problems with my phone, which are beyond my calculations:

- My phone's battery charge drops very quickly when the **mobile data** connection is on.
  Suppose, I am using my phone normally, the discharge rate is about **0.5% per minute**. But, if I keep the *mobile data connection on*, then the discharge rate becomes about **5% per minute**!!!.
- Suppose, I am using my phone while I can see that the charge is 30%. Suddenly, I am notified of 0% battery and the Android OS shuts down. When I plug in the charger, it boots up and again shows 30% charge!!!
  See this screenshot:
  [image]
- Suppose, I pull out the battery when the charge is 50%, after reinserting the battery, the charge either becomes 70% or as low as 20%, which are completely different from the previous observations.

All these happens when the **mobile data** *remains on*. I know that internet connection requires more energy, but according to me, it shouldn't be so much, isn't it?

I have two screenshots regarding this issue, where there are sudden *sharp drops* in the battery monitor graphs:
[image]

I had already *factory resetted* my phone and *uninstalled every suspected battery draining programs*, but it didn't solved the issue. Why does this happens and how to solve this issue? Please help me.

**Note :** My phone's model is **Micromax Bharat 3 Q437** with pre-installed *stock Android 7.0*.

Comment: Please mention your device name and model

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: If the device goes off at 30% there are two possibilities: Android initiates the shutdown or the voltage suddenly breaks in so that the CPU stops working and Android crashes. In the latter case the reason is a bad battery. If changing the battery for your device is possible with a reasonable effort you should replace the battery.

Comment: Can a 2000 mAh mobile battery get degraded within 1½ years?

Comment: Currently, I noticed that my phone's battery is holding just about 60% of charge. When I put the phone to charge, the charge raises from 40% to 80% within just a few minutes. And, while using the phone, it switches off at 40% charge. Sometimes, the charge drops from 60% to 20% very quickly. All these indicates that the battery is holding just about 60% charge. How to get rid of this?